# MS Excel - Sum of multiple cells if the cell contains "X"

Tags: excel

I need your help in this Excel file

first allow me to attach the following figure to ease the questions.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is the following I want to get a result in the red box that sums the total number of balls for only the cells that contains "X".

in other words:

if (system hosted in site - Cell filled with "X") Append the number of balls in the red box
where the number of balls are from the small table on the right.

gosh I tried my best to deliver my question , hope you got it :-)

Comment: Look at the `SUMIF` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way might be using a hidden column to compute the sums, and then pull the sum from this column into the visible column.

[image]

In column C here, I have entered the formula

`=IF(B2="X",VLOOKUP($A2,$G$2:$H$4,2,FALSE),"")` into C2

Then C6 is the SUM of C2:C4, and B6 is just `=C6`. Column C can be hidden, just leaving the sum visible without the intermediate computations.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:`=SUMIF(C4:C8;"=X";J5:J9)`. [Here is microsoft's man page for SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx)